# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function header() - Beginner question

Tags: php, authentication, session, redirect, header

My name is Thibaud, I'm beginner on PHP.
I'm trying to set up a login logic to my "app" and encountering this error :

*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function             header() in C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment11_autosession\login.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment11_autosession\login.php on line 15*

Here is my code :

```
session_start();
// If there is no parameter, error message is generated
if ( isset($_POST["who"])  && isset($_POST["pass"])) {
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$salt = 'hello';
$stored_hash = 'hello';
$md5 = hash('md5', $salt.$pass);
    unset($_SESSION["who"]);  // Logout current user
    if (filter_var($_POST["who"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && $md5 == $stored_hash) {
            $_SESSION["who"] = $_POST["who"];
            $_SESSION["success"] = "Logged in.";
           ** header('Location: view.php');**
            return;
    }
    elseif (!filter_var($_POST["who"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $_SESSION["error"] = "Email must have an at-sign (@)";
        header('Location: login.php');
        return;}
    elseif ( strlen($_POST["who"]) < 1 || strlen($_POST["pass"]) < 1 ) {
    $_SESSION["error"] = "User name and password are required";
    header('Location: login.php');
    return;}
    else{ $_SESSION["error"] = "Incorrect password.";
            header( 'Location: login.php' );
            return;}
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Thibaud  - login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Thibaud - login page</h1>
<p>
<form method="POST">
<label for="nam">User Name</label>
<input type="text" name="who" id="nam"><br/>
<label for="id_1723">Password</label>
<input type="text" name="pass" id="id_1723"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Log In">
<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">

</form>
</p>

<p>
<?php
    if ( isset($_SESSION["error"]) ) {
        echo('<p style="color:red">'.$_SESSION["error"]."</p>\n");
        unset($_SESSION["error"]);
        unset($_SESSION["pass"]);
    }
    else {echo('<p style="color:green">'.$_SESSION["success"]."</p>\n");
        unset($_SESSION["success"]);
        unset($_SESSION["pass"]);
    }
?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to find out more about this error message on google. I understood it could be :

- a syntax issue
- a call to a function that has not been declared yet.

But I did not find signs of this in my code yet...

When I test to put a bad "who" or a bad "pass", browser redirection to the same page works well (http response 302 in the network console and refresh of the page). It's only in the case of a correct "who" and correct "pass" that the redirection to this other "view.php" page does not occur and I get this error message.

I tried to modify the syntax of this header() before and after, I tried to copy from another piece of code where it was working, but error remains there.

I hope this question is in the correct format and thanks a lot in advance for your help on this one :)
Best Regards,
Thibaud.

Comment: I don’t know what your specific problem is, but if you are new to PHP, please forget about MD5 and learn the [modern way](https://3v4l.org/XnYbg) for password hashing and verification. Also, your first `if` does password testing and the subsequent statements perform input validation. Usually the former is the last thing done after the input has been confirmed to be valid

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for this valuable comment, I'll invert those statements :-)
Regarding the MD5 hashing, indeed I did not plan to use this in real life for password hashing, this was only an exercise on these sessions management and header() function for redirection. But again thank you for checking my topic and don't hesitate if you have further notes to help me improve !! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a further look at the code, I reworked it. This version of this code works well. I am not sure of the exact reason it's working but still, I let it here so that if a similar issue is coming for someone, he/she'll be able to retrieve a correct logic :

```
<?php

session_start();
// If there is no parameter, error message is generated
if ( isset($_POST["who"])  && isset($_POST["pass"])) {
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$salt = 'XyZzy12*_';
$stored_hash = '1a52e17fa899cf40fb04cfc42e6352f1';
$md5 = hash('md5', $salt.$pass);
    unset($_SESSION["who"]);  // Logout current user
    if (filter_var($_POST["who"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && $md5 == $stored_hash) {
            $_SESSION["who"] = $_POST["who"];
            $_SESSION["success"] = "Logged in.";
            header('Location: view.php');
            return;}
    elseif (!filter_var($_POST["who"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $_SESSION["error"] = "Email must have an at-sign (@)";
            header('Location: login.php');
            return;}
    elseif ( strlen($_POST["who"]) < 1 || strlen($_POST["pass"]) < 1 ) {
            $_SESSION["error"] = "User name and password are required";
            header('Location: login.php');
            return;}
    else{ $_SESSION["error"] = "Incorrect password.";
            header( 'Location: login.php' );
            return;}
}
?>


<html>
<head>
<title>Thibaud LOYRIAC  - AUTOSDB - login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Thibaud LOYRIAC  - AUTOSDB - login page</h1>
<p>
<form method="POST">
<label for="nam">User Name</label>
<input type="text" name="who" id="nam"><br/>
<label for="id_1723">Password</label>
<input type="text" name="pass" id="id_1723"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Log In">
<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">

</form>
</p>

<p>
<?php
    if ( isset($_SESSION["error"]) ) {
        echo('<p style="color:red">'.$_SESSION["error"]."</p>\n");
        unset($_SESSION["error"]);
        unset($_SESSION["pass"]);
    }
    elseif ( isset($_SESSION["success"]) ) {
    echo('<p style="color:green">'.$_SESSION["success"]."</p>\n");
        unset($_SESSION["success"]);
        unset($_SESSION["pass"]);
    }
?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Thibaud.